# How do I handle string feature in Recursive feature elimination or model training using SVM?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have data which looks like this

```
shift_id    user_id status  organization_id location_id department_id   open_positions  city    zip role_id specialty_id    latitude    longitude   years_of_experience                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
2   9   S   1   1   19  1   brooklyn    48001   2   9   42.643  -82.583                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
6   60  S   12  19  20  1   test    68410   3   7   40.608  -95.856                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
9   61  S   12  19  20  1   new york    48001   1   7   42.643  -82.583                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
10  60  S   12  19  20  1   test    68410   3   7   40.608  -95.856                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
21  3   S   1   1   19  1   pune    48001   1   2   46.753  -89.584 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
4   7   S   1   1   19  1   needham 2494    4   4   42.292  -71.246 2
```

So it contains string as well as numerical features.

I first want to perform Feature elimination and then SVM on it.

Here is my code to do it.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv",header = 0)
data = dataset.drop('organization_id',1)
#data = data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
target = dataset.location_id
#dataset.head()
svm = LinearSVC()
rfe = RFE(svm, 3)
rfe = rfe.fit(data, target)
print(rfe.support_)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

But as column `status` has string value, it is giving -

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'S'`

Having such string feature is obvious. What is the standard practice to handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the error by encoding each categorical feature as an integer value through [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

enc = OrdinalEncoder()
features = ['status', 'city']
categorical = data[features]
enc.fit(categorical)
numerical = enc.transform(categorical)

for n, feat in enumerate(features):
    data[feat] = numerical[:, n]
```

If this approach does not work for you, I would recommend that you try [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) instead.